# How do you activate routes through a service in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an angular app where I have a "welcome page" component set as the default route so it's the first to pop up when a user comes to the site.  Within that component I have links that need to activate the `router-outlet` in the app component.  Seeing that the "welcome page component" is pulled in by the router outlet I figured I'd have to use a service to detect the link clicked and update the route in the app component because there's nothing explicit between the two components to pass it through otherwise.

I created a service file which looks like this

```
@Injectable()

export class RouteService{

    public clickedLink: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    setLink(link: string){ this.clickedLink.next(link); }
}
```

I modified my "welcome page component" to look like this

```
export class WelcomePageComponent {

    constructor(private RS: RouteService ){}

    sendLink(link: string){ this.RS.setLink(link); }
}
```

then modified the links in the template to this

```
<a (click)="sendLink('/illustration')"></a>
```

then in the app component I have this

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    pageLink: string;

    constructor( private RS: RouteService, private router: Router ){}

    ngOnInit(){
       this.RS.clickedLink.subscribe(link => this.pageLink = link); 
    }

    pageNav(link:string){ this.router.navitgate(link); }
}
```

Now I'm stuck at figuring out how I should go about triggering the `pageNav()` function to update the route.  I looked into `@HostListener` in terms of trying to listen to the `pageLink` variable and a little into observables but can't seem to find anything relevant to what I'm trying to achieve.  Can anyone help with this?

**UPDATE**

my `app.module` looks like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      PagesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `PagesModule` is a module I started for my "page components" and that looks like this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [
        WelcomePageComponent, IllustrationPageComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        WelcomePageComponent, IllustrationPageComponent
    ]
})

export class PagesModule{}
```

the `AppRoutingModule` looks like this

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'welcome',      component: WelcomePageComponent },
    { path: 'illustration', component: IllustrationPageComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: this.RS.clickedLink.subscribe(link => { this.pageLink = link; this.pageNav(link); });

Comment: @HostListener is only to listen javascript events.

Comment: ok that's in the `ngOnInit` though, how is it suppose to know when someone clicks something after the page is loaded?

Comment: You are using Subject. So when you click on button, you use next() on it. All subscribers will be notified of this "next" call and do an action. You currently do "this.pageLink = link" as action. Add a call to your function by replacing it with "{ this.pageLink = link; this.pageNav(link); }". So "this.pageNav(link);"  will be called every times you will call "next()".

Comment: hmm. if that's the case then I don't even need the `pageLink` variable.  Though I just tried this and it's not working.

Comment: Your right, pageLink is not usefull. To see if your subscribe is called, update with this :
this.RS.clickedLink.subscribe(link => { console.log('clicked ! ', link); this.pageNav(link); }); 
and look at your console. PS: Did you write "navitgate" in your code ? this is "navigate".

Comment: nothing logs into the console.  What do you mean in terms of me writing "navigate" in my code?  I put it in the `pageNav` function to trigger.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Look again at your "navitgate" ( navi --- > t <--- gate ). Can you say where you provide your RouterService ? Is it nicely in the same Module and not on each Components ?

Comment: ooooh wow I didn't see that lol.  and I do have my service on each component.

Comment: Can you add your Module and components decorators in your question ?

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: I can't see any provider in your modules. So you probably put it on your Component decorator (already not in your question). If you do that, you will have deferent instance of RouteService on each component. What you need is a singleton service so please remove it from components providers and add it in your module providers.

Comment: I just removed the `providers: [ RouteService ]` from the `app.component` and `welcome-page.component` and added it to the providers in the `app.module`.  When I click the link it console.logs now but I get a Type error saying `commands.reduce is not a function` and nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: navigate need an array so use this.router.navigate([link]);

Comment: If it's good for you i will create an answer that groupe every steps.

Comment: actually that would be great because then I could mark it as the right answer because it worked lol.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve your problems by these steps:

- Currently you **already listen click** by subscribing clickedLink. When link is clicked, you save the new link in "pageLink" but you can **do more actions** (call pageNav() for example).

  You will not need pageLink anymore if you directly call pageNav(link).

  `this.RS.clickedLink.subscribe(link => { this.pageNav(link); });`
- Be sure you use **singleton service** for "RouterService". Have different instances of it will not allow you to emit events across components.
  To do that : provide the service **only on parent module** of your components. (remove it from your components providers list)
- router.navigate() **require an array** therefore you can use it like this : `this.router.navigate([link]);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I am fully understanding your question but routing in angular is very easy to configure and implement. Just add `routerLink` directive to any element and it will update the router-outlet when it's clicked. here is an example

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard">
       dashboard
    </a>
    <a routerLink="/path-to-another-component">
       new componenet
    </a>
</nav>
```

the router link directive call the angular routing service behind the scene, checking you router configurations find the component to be rendered and update the router-outlet.

There is no need for observable here. I hope that help you.